# Mouseenter Hover Div Show/Hide

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get my function to work with no success. All I need is to be able to scroll onto my div and for the X to show up and then I can add my wanted effects afterwards.

I'm using Javascript as I need it cross browser compatible. I don't want to use CSS as its very limited in what I would like to add in the future.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.userinfo').hover({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).children('div.delete').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).children('div.delete').hide();

    }
    });
    });
</script>
    <?
echo "<div class='userinfo'><div class='delete' style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');\">X</div></div>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method instead of hover:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div.userinfo').bind({
     mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).children('div.delete').show();
     },
     mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).children('div.delete').hide();
     }
   });
});
```

Note: If you are adding new dom elements later with jQuery, use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), if you are not, use bind method which is really solid way.

Comment: It has worked. Thank you so much. Will accept as answer and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of .hover(), which is deprecated and doesnt work like you try to use it, use .on():

```
$(function() {
    $('div.userinfo').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).children('div.delete').show();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).children('div.delete').hide();

        }
    });
});
```

This will do the job.

Comment: according to firebug TypeError: $("div.userinfo").on is not a function

I tried this before .hover

Comment: Which verson of jQuery are you using?
And instead of on, as shown in the other answer, you can use .bind which also works with older versions of jQuery, but may become deprecated in the future

Comment: Ok, then .on should exist.. Dunno why it doesnt work then. Cannot be because .bind simply calls .on under the hook, so this is very strange.

Comment: It maybe because I've used an older version on some other functions. 

How would I add a div with an id such as 
'divider-".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'